How to create stripe token for backend payment in flutter
I want to create a stripe token which I send to the backend API for payments.I created a CardFormField then I used :
 final tokenData = await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
      params: const PaymentMethodParams.card(
        paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(),
      ),
    );
    print('token is : ${tokenData.id}');

I used this method to create token but when I pass this token to API it says the You cannot create a charge with a PaymentMethod. Use the Payment Intents API instead.
If this method is not correct and there is any other way then please correct me.

Does this answer your question? You cannot create a charge with a PaymentMethod. Use the Payment Intents API instead
